# Python dictionary not updating key with all values of list I'm iterating through

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to create a python dictionary based on a list and dump it to a JSON file.

Here is my code:

```
outfile = "metadata.json"
metadata = {}
dockers = ["eg-submitter", "rnastar", "egnorm"]

with open(outfile, 'w') as json_file:
    for docker in dockers[1:]:
        metadata["job"] = {docker: conf["JOB_PARAMS"][docker]}
    json.dump(metadata, json_file)
```

I want the output JSON file to look like the following:

```
{
  "job": {
    "egnorm": {
        "inputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "logdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "projectid": "gene_expression",
        "geneannotfile": "s3://eg-genome-dev/hg19/RS_gene_table.csv",
        "scalingfactor": "13.07",
        "aligner_type": "rnastar",
        "outputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "binsize": "75"
    },
    "rnastar": {
        "inputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "logdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "projectid": "gene_expression",
        "geneannotfile": "s3://eg-genome-dev/hg19/RS_gene_table.csv",
        "scalingfactor": "13.07",
        "aligner_type": "rnastar",
        "outputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "binsize": "75"
    }
  }
}
```

But instead, the JSON file is coming out like so:

```
{
  "job": {
    "egnorm": {
        "inputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "logdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "projectid": "gene_expression",
        "geneannotfile": "s3://eg-genome-dev/hg19/RS_gene_table.csv",
        "scalingfactor": "13.07",
        "aligner_type": "rnastar",
        "outputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
        "binsize": "75"
    }
  }
}
```

It's only adding one of the elements from my `dockers` list to `metadata` instead of both elements (and yes, I do want to skip the first element `eg-submitter`, which is why I'm iterating through dockers[1:]).

When I print `docker` under the for loop, both `egnorm` and `rnastar` are printed out. I also tried variations of initializing the `metadata` dict and then something like the following, but still get the same issue:

```
for docker in dockers[1:]:
   if docker not in metadata:
       metadata["job"] = {docker: conf["JOB_PARAMS"][docker]}
json.dump(metadata, json_file)
```

Note: `conf` is just a dictionary I'm importing from another file that contains the necessary parameters for each docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first iteration your `metadata["job"]` equals:

```
"rnastar": {
    "inputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "logdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "projectid": "gene_expression",
    "geneannotfile": "s3://eg-genome-dev/hg19/RS_gene_table.csv",
    "scalingfactor": "13.07",
    "aligner_type": "rnastar",
    "outputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "binsize": "75"
}
```

In the second iteration, you override `metadata["job"]` to be equal

```
"egnorm": {
    "inputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "logdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "projectid": "gene_expression",
    "geneannotfile": "s3://eg-genome-dev/hg19/RS_gene_table.csv",
    "scalingfactor": "13.07",
    "aligner_type": "rnastar",
    "outputdir": "s3://eg-seq-processed/RNA_expression/",
    "binsize": "75"
}
```

To solve the issue you can initialize `metadata["job"]` to empty dictionary. 
Then you can add new key,value mapping using `metadata["job"][docker] = conf["JOB_PARAMS"][docker]`

So below code should achieve what you require:

```
outfile = "metadata.json"
metadata = {}
dockers = ["eg-submitter", "rnastar", "egnorm"]

with open(outfile, 'w') as json_file:
    metadata["job"] = {}
    for docker in dockers[1:]:
        metadata["job"][docker] = conf["JOB_PARAMS"][docker]
    json.dump(metadata, json_file)
```

Comment: So how do I not override it, but rather append to the `metadata["job"]` key?